# Remote development of Visual C++ applications from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, visual-c++, ssh

Remote development **on** Linux **from** Windows is easily doable via SSH.

However, what about the other way? I need to build and debug my Visual C++ application on Windows, but I want to work on a Linux system.

1. Cross-compiling via MinGW doesn't work because of MSVC-specific libraries
2. Ubuntu on Windows is a good start, but I'd like to work on a real Linux system
3. RDP/VNC or something like that doesn't help either, because than I'd work on Windows again
4. So does a virtual machine

Maybe something like Powershell on Linux + SSH to the Windows Powershell?

Comment: If remote management is enabled on the Windows side, you can `Enter-PSSession` to a remote Windows machine. You can't edit files that way, but you should be able to run command-line build tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I regularly develop Visual C# applications remotely from Linux, not MSVC for the most part, but, like you, I wanted to find a way to build and debug Windows-targeted applications and libraries on remote Windows machines without working directly in the box using RDP, Visual Studio, etc.

It's difficult to answer this question without more information about the development and debugging tools you prefer to use on Linux for the types of applications you develop. I'll try to provide a general overview and update the answer for details you add about your workflow.

[Cygwin](https://cygwin.org/), similar to [MinGW's MSYS](http://mingw.org/wiki/msys), provides a Unix-like environment for Windows. Most importantly, Cygwin, unlike MinGW/MSYS, includes an implementation of the OpenSSH server that enables us to connect to the Windows box over SSH from Linux (or any other device with an SSH client, really). We can install the *sshd* package using Cygwin's setup utility. After connecting, Cygwin drops us into a Bash shell by default. With this capability, we can:

- Execute remote commands and scripts over SSH.
- Edit files using our favorite *nix command-line text editor (Vim, Emacs, etc.)
- Mount remote filesystems locally using [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) (if Windows shares are unavailable).
- Forward or tunnel ports if needed.

The availability of a general-purpose shell makes *almost* anything possible. We can execute batch files, PowerShell scripts, and native Windows executables from Cygwin's shell environment in addition to Linux scripts and Cygwin programs.

For example, we could [run *msbuild*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx) from the SSH session command line to build our VC++ application or we could configure our local GUI editor or IDE running in Linux to execute *msbuild* over SSH when we click the "build" button.

We could set up a similar environment in recent versions of Windows using the [*Windows Subsystem for Linux*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) ("WSL", Bash on Windows). I personally prefer Cygwin for greater portability and ease of configuration. Cygwin's *sshd* can run as a Windows service, and, as an established project, Cygwin integrates *very well* with Windows systems (user accounts, filesystems, Windows APIs, etc.).

**Working with Code**

We can choose from several workflows depending on our tools and comfort-level with the command-line:

1. Completely text-based—all work performed through the SSH session
2. Use local tools on files mounted in a remote filesystem
3. Use local tools and synchronize files

I use the first approach. I'm a heavy Vim user, so I connect to Windows machines over SSH to do my work on the command-line using the tools and environment provided by Cygwin. The availability of tools typically found on Linux simplifies many tasks that are hard to do from the default Windows console. We can write shell scripts to automate tasks that Visual Studio might normally do for us. For example, I wrote a wrapper script around *mstest* that reads the XML test results and outputs them in a format that's easy to read in a terminal.

If we prefer to use a GUI editor or IDE, we can mount the remote code locally so tools can read and write files as if they were part of the Linux machine's local filesystem. We likely still need to use SSH to execute commands needed to build the projects, but many editors allow us to configure this command as the project's "build" action.

Sometimes a remote filesystem is too slow for effective editing. In these cases, we can synchronize files between the Linux development machine and the Windows host using a tool like *rsync* or the editor's "upload on save" feature (over SFTP, for example), if available.

**Debugging**

Everything works pretty well until we try to find a way to debug our applications. As of now, there is *no reasonable substitute* for Visual Studio's debugger when working with Visual C++ projects. We can debug managed C# applications running on the CLR using [MDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mdbg-exe), but no comparable tool exists for C++ programs.

We can try to use *gdb* (from MinGW, Cygwin, etc.) for basic, low-level debugging of native binaries, like reading memory addresses, but the debugger does not yet support reading Microsoft's debugging symbols, so the debugging experience is very limited. Microsoft [began documenting](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb) the PDB format a couple years ago, so we may see some compatibility in the future. Even so, it will take a long time to produce a satisfactory alternative to Visual Studio's excellent debugging tools.

For debugging, RDP is currently our best—and probably, only—option. For a more native-feeling experience, we can run Visual Studio using [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org) (or other RDP client) and [seamlessrdp](https://github.com/rdesktop/seamlessrdp) to create a single-window RDP session of the Visual Studio IDE instead of a full desktop which integrates with whatever window manager we're using on Linux.

Sometimes we can get around launching a full Visual Studio debugging session for simple debugging scenarios by adding tracing to our application that outputs values to the console or to a log file. In many cases, this is faster than starting the debugger anyway.

We can also try to use [Eclipse's CDT debugger](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) configured for the Visual C++ toolchain. This may enable us to perform remote debugging using an Eclipse instance on the Linux machine. I have never tried this approach, and I expect there may be some issues when the application is linked against Microsoft's libraries.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the in-depth answer! I knew about Cygwin & Co (in fact, I'm using MSYS and WSL on my machine). However, what I was really looking for was working in a full Linux environment -- I just prefer its window managers, applications, and customizability.

Comment: @Julius I hear you--I prefer the Linux desktop as well. I think you understood that I suggested Cygwin, etc., only as a server. We'd connect to those from our Linux machine where we work. If you like GUI editors, VSCode with the [C++ extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/cc-extension-for-visual-studio-code/) should provide us with a decent dev environment (IntelliSense, etc) when opening a project mounted locally from a remote Windows machine. Unfortunately, we're still stuck with Visual Studio for debugging, but seamlessrdp lets us use it more like a native app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your requirements, but maybe you could use a gdbserver on Windows (from MinGW) and remote debug from VSCode on Linux - or any other environment you like. You can find more details in this post [here](https://medium.com/@spe_/debugging-c-c-programs-remotely-using-visual-studio-code-and-gdbserver-559d3434fb78). (Watch out, VSCode prevents you from running gdb unless it’s signed as mentioned in the first link.)
There is also a [Native Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) VSCode extension that could be helpful.

Another solution I can think of is to use [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/de/team-services/pricing/) (free for small teams up to 5 persons) as build server.

As you have said, the other way around is pretty easy and nowadays even [officially supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/04/29/debug-c-code-on-linux-from-visual-studio/) by Visual Studio 2017.

Most probably, the VS [remote debugging tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging) for Windows wont be helpful for you.